# How do you search for typing errors (dates) from a dataset and replace them based on criteria?

Tags: pandas, date, dataset, missing-data

I'm sorting a large old dataset with multiple typing errors. I want to clean up the documents by iterating over a row to find and change the type errors based on criteria. Now i get the error below when trying to remove hour minute second in pandas.

```
Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3016-03-09 00:00:00
```

What i'm thinking would be something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'raw data.xlsx', header = 0)


for date in Dates:
    if date is out of bounds date time:
        replace str[0-3] with Year, inplace = True


df['Date'].dt.year,month,day

print(df)
```

A typical dataset typing error can be the date in item 4

```
Item    Description Date    Year    ...
1   Ketchup400  2015-10-27 00:00:00 2015    ...
2   Ketchup600  2018-02-16 00:00:00 2018    ...
3   Mustard800  2015-10-02 00:00:00 2015    ...
4   Mustard200  3016-03-09 00:00:00 2016    ...
1   Ketchup400  2018-02-26 00:00:00 2018    ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

I want to remove the hour, minute and second from the dates, correct the dates and print the new file... The ouput should be something like:

```
Item    Description Date    Year    ...
1   Ketchup400  2015-10-27  2015    ...
2   Ketchup600  2018-02-16  2018    ...
3   Mustard800  2015-10-02  2015    ...
4   Mustard200  2016-03-09  2016    ...
1   Ketchup400  2018-02-26  2018    ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpliest solution is add column `Year` to spitted `Date` column by first `-` and convert to datetimes:

```
s = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Date'].astype(str).str.split('-', n=1).str[1]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce')
print (df)
   Item Description       Date  Year  ...
0     1  Ketchup400 2015-10-27  2015  ...
1     2  Ketchup600 2018-02-16  2018  ...
2     3  Mustard800 2015-10-02  2015  ...
3     4  Mustard200 2016-03-09  2016  ...
4     1  Ketchup400 2018-02-26  2018  ...
```

Another solution with better performance is get all non parsed datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `errors='coerce'` parameter, parsing only this filtered rows by check missing values and add to original by [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) rows processes like first solution:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

df1 = df[date.isna()]
print (df1)
   Item Description                 Date  Year  ...
3     4  Mustard200  3016-03-09 00:00:00  2016  ...

s = (pd.to_datetime(df1['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + 
                    df1['Date'].astype(str).str.split('-', n=1).str[1]))
print (s)
3   2016-03-09
dtype: datetime64[ns]

df['Date'] = date.combine_first(s)
print (df)
   Item Description       Date  Year  ...
0     1  Ketchup400 2015-10-27  2015  ...
1     2  Ketchup600 2018-02-16  2018  ...
2     3  Mustard800 2015-10-02  2015  ...
3     4  Mustard200 2016-03-09  2016  ...
4     1  Ketchup400 2018-02-26  2018  ...
```

Comment: I get the error: 'Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas' when using the line s=... . The dates are imported as dtype object.

Comment: @aosa - Can you change `df['Date'].str.split('-', n=1).str[1]` to `df['Date'].astype(str).str.split('-', n=1).str[1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this and also get invalid dates as NaT ;)

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

Note:

```
      Item Description                 Date  Year
0     1  Ketchup400  2015-10-27 00:00:00  2015
1     2  Ketchup600  2018-02-16 00:00:00  2018
2     3  Mustard800  2015-10-02 00:00:00  2015
3     4  Mustard200  3016-03-09 00:00:00  2016
4     1  Ketchup400  2018-02-26 00:00:00  2018
   Item Description                 Date  Year      Date2
0     1  Ketchup400  2015-10-27 00:00:00  2015 2015-10-27
1     2  Ketchup600  2018-02-16 00:00:00  2018 2018-02-16
2     3  Mustard800  2015-10-02 00:00:00  2015 2015-10-02
3     4  Mustard200  3016-03-09 00:00:00  2016        NaT
4     1  Ketchup400  2018-02-26 00:00:00  2018 2018-02-26
```

And then manually fix the parsing errors if possible, because NaT will help you identify the problems.